# plotting text into editable file using coordinates [win error 5 : access denied]

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm working on an code to plot characters from an image into an editable file in the same position as the image. I plan on extracting text coordinates and plotting them on a dxf file. the code is:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import ezdxf

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR'

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\kshet\OneDrive\Desktop\python oce\example.jpg')

# Preprocess the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)
gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Perform OCR using Pytesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')

# Split the text into words
words = text.split()

# Extract the coordinates of each word
dxf_entities = []
for word in words:
    result = pytesseract.image_to_data(gray, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT, config='--psm 6')
    n_boxes = len(result['level'])
    for i in range(n_boxes):
        if result['text'][i] == word:
            (x, y, w, h) = (result['left'][i], result['top'][i], result['width'][i], result['height'][i])
            x_center = x + w / 2
            y_center = y + h / 2
            dxf_entities.append({
                'type': 'text',
                'text': word,
                'insert': (x_center, y_center),
                'height': h / 2,
            })

# Plot the words on an EZDXF file
doc = ezdxf.new('R2010')
msp = doc.modelspace()

for entity in dxf_entities:
    if entity['type'] == 'text':
        msp.add_text(entity['text'], dxfattribs={
            'layer': 'TEXT',
            'height': entity['height'],
            'insert': entity['insert'],
        })

doc.saveas('output.dxf')
```

The error im getting is as followed:

tried running it as administrator it didnt work

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible code sample. I recommend you remove the code above `doc = ezdxf.new('R2010')` and replace it with initialization of the list `dxf_entities` to the values of the list at that position. Try other file name like `doc.saveas('output1.dxf')`. Try using full path: `doc.saveas('C:\\output.dxf')`